# Is pom or AppInitializer error dependency?

Tags: java, rest, web-applications, pom.xml

I have a problem with change my pom. The project now is with servlet and JSP and now i need REST API.
I change my POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>templateGestionale</groupId>
    <artifactId>templateGestionale</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- mysql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.24</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Oracle -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>18.3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- jsp-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- risolve errore web.xml mancante -->
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- imposta versione Java -->
                    <source>18</source>
                    <target>18</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And i create a package "config" with:

WebAppConfig:

```
package config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "controller")
public class WebAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver vResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewRes = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewRes.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view");
        viewRes.setSuffix(".jsp");
        viewRes.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return viewRes;

    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/res/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");

    }

}
```

and AppInizializer, but dont work,
error in package config "Multiple markers at this line
- The type jakarta.servlet.ServletContext cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type org.springframework.web.context.AbstractContextLoaderInitializer
- The type jakarta.servlet.ServletException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type org.springframework.web.context.AbstractContextLoaderInitializer":

```
package config;

import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        
        return new Class<?>[] {WebAppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
    @Override
    protected FrameworkServlet createDispatcherServlet(WebApplicationContext servletAppContext) {       
        return super.createDispatcherServlet(servletAppContext);
    }
}
```

How to resolve? Thanks

I think the error lies in the dependencies of the pom

Comment: It may be due to servlet from the javax.servlet package to the new jakarata.servlet. Please update javax.servlet.jsp and javax.servlet-api to jakarta one's and try. Then subsequently in your WebappConfig &  AppInitializer update the imports. Try clean build, think should be okay. Thankyou

Comment: Ok work! But all import in my servlet have a error... I change import in jackarta but dont work. In browser error 404.